# Oracle procedure with CDT as input parameters is very slow

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a couple of Oracle Custom Data types (CDT) and one of this is an input parameter to a stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENTITY_BR AS OBJECT(
    ID                 NUMBER
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENTITY_BR_LIST AS TABLE OF ENTITY_BR;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENTITY AS OBJECT(
    ID_C              VARCHAR2(25 BYTE),
    ID_I              NUMBER,
    NAME_C            VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    CODE_I            NUMBER,
    DESC_C            VARCHAR2(1024 BYTE),
    BR                ENTITY_BR_LIST
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENTITY_LIST AS TABLE OF ENTITY;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CRDS AS OBJECT(
    ID_I                    NUMBER,
    VERSION_I               NUMBER,
    STATUS_C                VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    ENTITY                  ENTITY_LIST
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LIST AS TABLE OF CRDS;
```

Now I have stored procedure as below. The input is CRDSLIST which is passed as an array of 5000 items at a time. This proc is taking hell of time to execute and the time increases on every execution. Any idea what could be going wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE LOAD AS
    PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA (crds CRDSLIST);
END;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY LOAD AS
PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA (crds IN CRDSLIST)
AS
    SID_I_NEW        NUMBER;
    ENTITY_SID_I_NEW NUMBER;
    LAST_DT          TIMESTAMP;
    ELAPSED_TIME     NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1 .. crds.COUNT
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                SELECT MAX(LAST_UPDATED_DT) INTO LAST_DT
                FROM T_REF1
                GROUP BY ID_I
                HAVING ID_I = crds(i).ID_I;

                EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN LAST_DT := NULL;
            END;

            IF LAST_DT IS NOT NULL THEN
                SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE - LAST_DT) *24 * 60 * 60) +
                             (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE - LAST_DT) * 60 * 60) +
                             (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SYSDATE - LAST_DT) * 60) +
                             EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SYSDATE - LAST_DT)
                INTO ELAPSED_TIME
                FROM dual;
            END IF;

            IF LAST_DT IS NULL OR ELAPSED_TIME >= 60 THEN
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO T_REF1(SID_I, ID_I, VERSION_I, ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT)
                    VALUES(SEQ1_SID.NEXTVAL, crds(i).ID_I, crds(i).VERSION_I, crds(i).ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, SYSDATE) RETURNING SID_I INTO SID_I_NEW;

                    FOR j IN 1 .. crds(i).ENTITY.COUNT
                    LOOP
                        INSERT INTO T_REF2(SID_I, UCM_SID_I, ID_C, ID_I, NAME_C) VALUES(SEQ2_SID.NEXTVAL, SID_I_NEW, crds(i).ENTITY(j).ID_C, crds(i).ENTITY(j).ID_I, crds(i).ENTITY(j).NAME_C)                          RETURNING SID_I INTO ENTITY_SID_I_NEW;

                        IF crds(i).ENTITY(j).BR IS NOT NULL THEN
                            FOR k IN 1 .. crds(i).ENTITY(j).BR.COUNT
                            LOOP
                                INSERT INTO T_REF3(SID_I, ENTITY_SID_I, BR_ID, VERSION_I, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES(SEQ3_SID.NEXTVAL, ENTITY_SID_I_NEW, crds(i).ENTITY(j).BR(k).ID_I, crds(i).VERSION_I, SYSDATE);
                            END LOOP;
                        END IF;

                        IF (crds(i).ENTITY(j).DESC_C IS NOT NULL) THEN
                            INSERT INTO T_REF2_VALIDATION(SID_I, ENTITY_SID_I, ERROR_CODE_I, ERROR_DESC_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES(SEQ4_SID.NEXTVAL, ENTITY_SID_I_NEW, crds(i).ENTITY(j).CODE_I, crds(i).ENTITY(j).DESC_C, SYSDATE);
                        END IF;
                    END LOOP;

                    IF (crds(i).ERROR_DESC_C IS NOT NULL) THEN
                        INSERT INTO T_REF1_VALIDATION(SID_I, UCM_SID_I, ERROR_CODE_I, ERROR_DESC_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES(SEQ5_SID.NEXTVAL, SID_I_NEW, crds(i).CODE_I, crds(i).DESC_C, SYSDATE);
                    END IF;
                END;
            END IF;

        END LOOP;

        COMMIT;
    END;
```

> ---
>
> ```
>  UPDATE
> ```
>
> ---

I came up with this solution which looks clean but taking around 3 seconds to insert 5000 records in all the related tables. Any points to improve this would be highly appreciated.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA2 (UCMS IN UCMLIST1)
AS
  V_IDS       KEY_VALUES;
  V_UCM       KEY_VALUES;
  V_ENTITY    KEY_VALUES;
  V_BR        KEY_VALUES;
  V_UCMS      UCMLIST1;
  V_UCMS_VAL  UCMLIST1;
  V_ENTITIES  UCM_ENTITY_LIST1;
  V_BRS       UCM_ENTITY_BR_LIST1;
BEGIN
  -- FIND ALL ID WHICH NEEDS PROCESSING, DISCARD THOSE IDS PROCESSED WITHIN LAST 60 SECONDS
  SELECT CASE 
    WHEN T.ID_I IS NULL
      THEN KEY_VALUE(V.ID_I, NULL)
      ELSE KEY_VALUE(T.ID_I, NULL)
    END
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_IDS
  FROM T_REF_UCM T
  RIGHT JOIN TABLE (UCMS) V ON T.ID_I = V.ID_I
  GROUP BY T.ID_I
    ,V.ID_I
  HAVING GET_SECONDS(SYSDATE, MAX(T.LAST_UPDATED_DT)) >= 60
    OR T.ID_I IS NULL;

  -- Prepare to insert using forall
  SELECT UCM1(NULL
    ,CRD.ID_I
    ,CRD.VERSION_I
    ,CRD.ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C
    ,CRD.IM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
    ,CRD.VM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
    ,CRD.IM_START_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.IM_END_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.VM_START_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.VM_END_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.ERROR_CODE_I
    ,CRD.ERROR_DESC_C
    ,CRD.ENTITY)
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_UCMS
  FROM TABLE (V_IDS) T
  INNER JOIN TABLE (UCMS) CRD ON T.ID_I = CRD.ID_I;

  -- Insert into T_REF_UCM
  FORALL I IN 1 .. V_UCMS.COUNT
    INSERT INTO T_REF_UCM (SID_I
      ,ID_I
      ,VERSION_I
      ,ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C
      ,IM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
      ,VM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
      ,IM_START_DATE_DT
      ,IM_END_DATE_DT
      ,VM_START_DATE_DT
      ,VM_END_DATE_DT
      ,LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    VALUES(SEQ_UCM_SID.NEXTVAL
      ,V_UCMS(I).ID_I
      ,V_UCMS(I).VERSION_I
      ,V_UCMS(I).ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C
      ,V_UCMS(I).IM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
      ,V_UCMS(I).VM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
      ,V_UCMS(I).IM_START_DATE_DT
      ,V_UCMS(I).IM_END_DATE_DT
      ,V_UCMS(I).VM_START_DATE_DT
      ,V_UCMS(I).VM_END_DATE_DT
      ,SYSDATE)
    RETURNING KEY_VALUE(ID_I, SID_I) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_UCM;

  -- Prepare to insert in validation using forall
  SELECT UCM1(T.SID_I
    ,CRD.ID_I
    ,CRD.VERSION_I
    ,CRD.ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C
    ,CRD.IM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
    ,CRD.VM_IN_SCOPE_FLAG_C
    ,CRD.IM_START_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.IM_END_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.VM_START_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.VM_END_DATE_DT
    ,CRD.ERROR_CODE_I
    ,CRD.ERROR_DESC_C
    ,CRD.ENTITY)
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_UCMS_VAL
  FROM TABLE (V_UCM) T
  INNER JOIN TABLE (V_UCMS) CRD ON T.ID_I = CRD.ID_I
  WHERE CRD.ERROR_DESC_C IS NOT NULL;

  FORALL I IN 1 .. V_UCMS_VAL.COUNT
    INSERT INTO T_REF_UCM_VALIDATION (SID_I
      ,UCM_SID_I
      ,ERROR_CODE_I
      ,ERROR_DESC_C
      ,VERSION_I
      ,LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    VALUES(SEQ_UCM_VALIDATION_SID.NEXTVAL
      ,V_UCMS_VAL(I).SID_I
      ,V_UCMS_VAL(I).ERROR_CODE_I
      ,V_UCMS_VAL(I).ERROR_DESC_C
      ,V_UCMS_VAL(I).VERSION_I
      ,SYSDATE);

  -- Prepare to insert entity using forall
  SELECT UCM_ENTITY1(U.SID_I
    ,ENT.AMINETID_C
    ,ENT.ENTITYID_I
    ,ENT.LEGAL_NAME_C
    ,ENT.JURISDICTION_C
    ,ENT.JURIS_EFF_DT
    ,ENT.IG_EXEMPTION
    ,ENT.IG_EXEMPTION_START_DT
    ,ENT.IG_EXEMPTION_END_DT
    ,ENT.ERROR_CODE_I
    ,ENT.ERROR_DESC_C
    ,ENT.BR)
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_ENTITIES
  FROM TABLE (V_UCM) U 
  INNER JOIN TABLE (V_UCMS) T ON U.ID_I = T.ID_I
  CROSS JOIN TABLE (ENTITY) ENT;

  FORALL I IN 1 .. V_ENTITIES.COUNT
    INSERT INTO T_REF_UCM_ENTITY (SID_I
      ,UCM_SID_I
      ,AMINETID_C
      ,ENTITYID_I
      ,LEGAL_NAME_C
      ,JURISDICTION_C
      ,JURIS_EFF_DT
      ,IG_EXEMPTION
      ,IG_EXEMPTION_START_DT
      ,IG_EXEMPTION_END_DT
      ,LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    VALUES (SEQ_UCM_ENTITY_SID.NEXTVAL
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).SID_I
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).AMINETID_C
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).ENTITYID_I
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).LEGAL_NAME_C
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).JURISDICTION_C
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).JURIS_EFF_DT
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).IG_EXEMPTION
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).IG_EXEMPTION_START_DT
      ,V_ENTITIES(I).IG_EXEMPTION_END_DT
      ,SYSDATE)
    RETURNING KEY_VALUE(SID_I, UCM_SID_I)
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_ENTITY;

  -- Prepare to insert BR using forall
  SELECT UCM_ENTITY_BR1(E.ID_I
    ,B.ID_I)
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_BRS
  FROM TABLE (V_ENTITY) E 
  INNER JOIN TABLE (V_ENTITIES) T ON E.SID_I = T.SID_I
  CROSS JOIN TABLE (BR) B;

  FORALL I IN 1 .. V_BRS.COUNT
    INSERT INTO T_REF_UCM_ENTITY_BR (SID_I
      ,ENTITY_SID_I
      ,BR_ID
      ,LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    VALUES (SEQ_UCM_ENTITY_BR_SID.NEXTVAL
      ,V_BRS(I).ENTITY_SID_I
      ,V_BRS(I).ID_I
      ,SYSDATE);

  COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Why do you create an `OBJECT` Type with only one single attribute? Use a simple scalar value instead, i.e. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ENTITY_BR_LIST AS TABLE OF NUMBER;`

Comment: Do you have set `CACHE` on your `SEQUENCE`? It will increase performance significantly.

Comment: @Wernfried, Thats just an example Type, it has many fields. Yes CACHE is set.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach goes into this direction (not tested):

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA (crds IN CRDSLIST) AS
    SID_I_NEW        NUMBER;
    ENTITY_SID_I_NEW NUMBER;
    LAST_DT          TIMESTAMP;
    ELAPSED_TIME     NUMBER;

    CURSOR cur_LAST_DT IS
    SELECT (SYSDATE - MAX(LAST_UPDATED_DT)) * 24*60*60 AS ELAPSED_TIME, o.*
    FROM T_REF1 t
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE(crds) o ON t.ID_I = o.ID_I
    GROUP BY t.ID_I;

BEGIN
    FOR crd IN cur_LAST_DT LOOP
        IF crd.ELAPSED_TIME >= 60 THEN
             BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO T_REF1(SID_I, ID_I, VERSION_I, ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT)
                  VALUES(SEQ1_SID.NEXTVAL, crd.ID_I, crd.VERSION_I, crd.ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, SYSDATE) 
                  RETURNING SID_I INTO SID_I_NEW;

                  FOR j IN 1 .. crd.ENTITY.COUNT LOOP
                        INSERT INTO T_REF2(SID_I, UCM_SID_I, ID_C, ID_I, NAME_C) VALUES (SEQ2_SID.NEXTVAL, SID_I_NEW, crd.ENTITY(j).ID_C, crd.ENTITY(j).ID_I, crd.ENTITY(j).NAME_C)                          
                        RETURNING SID_I INTO ENTITY_SID_I_NEW;

                        IF crd.ENTITY(j).BR IS NOT NULL THEN
                             FOR k IN 1 .. crd.ENTITY(j).BR.COUNT LOOP
                                  INSERT INTO T_REF3(SID_I, ENTITY_SID_I, BR_ID, VERSION_I, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES (SEQ3_SID.NEXTVAL, ENTITY_SID_I_NEW, crd.ENTITY(j).BR(k).ID_I, crd.VERSION_I, SYSDATE);
                             END LOOP;
                        END IF;

                        IF (crd.ENTITY(j).DESC_C IS NOT NULL) THEN
                             INSERT INTO T_REF2_VALIDATION(SID_I, ENTITY_SID_I, ERROR_CODE_I, ERROR_DESC_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES (SEQ4_SID.NEXTVAL, ENTITY_SID_I_NEW, crd.ENTITY(j).CODE_I, crd.ENTITY(j).DESC_C, SYSDATE);
                        END IF;
                  END LOOP;

                  IF (crd.ERROR_DESC_C IS NOT NULL) THEN
                        INSERT INTO T_REF1_VALIDATION(SID_I, UCM_SID_I, ERROR_CODE_I, ERROR_DESC_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT) VALUES (SEQ5_SID.NEXTVAL, SID_I_NEW, crd.CODE_I, crd.DESC_C, SYSDATE);
                  END IF;
             END;
        END IF;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

However, you should remove the loops as much as possible. Try this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TT_CRDS (CRDS_OBJ  CRDS_LIST)
NESTED TABLE CRDS_OBJ STORE AS NT_CRDS_LIST 
    (NESTED TABLE ENTITY STORE AS NT_ENTITY 
        (NESTED TABLE BR STORE AS NT_BR) 
    )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CRDS AS
SELECT * 
FROM TT_CRDS
    NATURAL JOIN TABLE(CRDS_OBJ) crds;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_ENTITY AS
SELECT ent.*
FROM TT_CRDS
    NATURAL JOIN TABLE(CRDS_OBJ) crds
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(ENTITY) ent;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_BR AS
SELECT ent.*, br.*
FROM TT_CRDS
    NATURAL JOIN TABLE(CRDS_OBJ) crds
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(ENTITY) ent
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(BR) br


PROCEDURE INSERT_DATA (crds IN CRDSLIST) AS
    TYPE SID_I_NEW_LIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    SID_I_NEW SID_I_NEW_LIST;
    ENTITY_SID_I_NEW SID_I_NEW_LIST;
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM TT_CRDS;
   INSERT INTO TT_CRDS (CRDS_OBJ) VALUES (crds);

    INSERT INTO T_REF1(SID_I, ID_I, VERSION_I, ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    SELECT SEQ1_SID.NEXTVAL, crd.ID_I, crd.VERSION_I, crd.ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C, SYSDATE
    FROM T_REF1 t
      RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE(crds) crd ON t.ID_I = crd.ID_I
    GROUP BY crd.ID_I, crd.VERSION_I, crd.ENTITY_IND_STATUS_C
    HAVING (SYSDATE - MAX(LAST_UPDATED_DT)) >= 60 OR MAX(LAST_UPDATED_DT) IS NULL
    RETURNING SID_I BULK COLLECT INTO SID_I_NEW;

    INSERT INTO T_REF2 (SID_I, UCM_SID_I, ID_C, ID_I, NAME_C)
    SELECT SEQ2_SID.NEXTVAL, SID_I_NEW, crd.ID_C, crd.ID_I, crd.NAME_C
    FROM TABLE(crds) crd
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(ENTITY) ent
    RETURNING SID_I BULK COLLECT INTO ENTITY_SID_I_NEW;

    INSERT INTO T_REF3 (SID_I, ENTITY_SID_I, BR_ID, VERSION_I, LAST_UPDATED_DT)
    SELECT SEQ3_SID.NEXTVAL, ENTITY_SID_I_NEW, crd.ID_I, crd.VERSION_I, SYSDATE
    FROM JOIN TABLE(crds) crd
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(ENTITY) ent
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(BR) br
    WHERE BR IS NOT NULL;

END;
```

This is not a working solution but it should give you an idea how it may look like. The temporary tables and views are not intended for your production but they will help you to develop the proper INSERT statements.

Comment: The first approach reduced insertion time to under 15 minutes for 1.5 million records. I would like to improve on it. I am a bit lost on the 2nd approach though it appears to be more promising.